# React hook form set Value not working for Radio Buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

On Button Click I want set the value as male or female

Child Components

```
const NewRad = (props) => {
  const {...rest } = props
  const { control , setValue} = useFormContext()
  const onButtonClick =()=>setValue('salaried', 'yes')
  return (    
    <Controller control={control} name='salaried'
      render={({ field: { value, onChange}, fieldState: { error }}) => {
        return (<FormControl  {...rest}>
            <FormLabel id="demo-error-radios"> Gender</FormLabel>
              <RadioGroup>
               <FormControlLabel value='male' control={<Radio />} label='Male' />
               <FormControlLabel value='female' control={<Radio />} label='Female' />             
              </RadioGroup>                                    
            </FormControl>)}} /> )
}
export default NewRad
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ok after some debugging, I checked the browser console logs and I found it was showing me this error:

```
Material-UI: A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of RadioGroup to be controlled.
Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled RadioGroup element for the lifetime of the component.
The nature of the state is determined during the first render, it's considered controlled if the value is not `undefined`.
```

To fix it, I set the defaultValue for my radio group name to "null" so that it wasn't undefined:

`MyForm.tsx`

```js
export default function MyForm() {
  const methods = useForm<any>({ defaultValues: { myRadioGroupName: null } });
    
  useEffect(() => {
    methods.setValue('myRadioGroupName', 'no');
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <Box display="flex" p={3}>
        <MyRadioGroup />
      </Box>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}
```

`MyRadioGroup.tsx`

```js
export default function MyRadioGroup() {
  const { control, register } = useFormContext();
  const myRadioGroupValue = useWatch({ control, name: 'myRadioGroupName' });

  return (
    <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" style={{ gap: '1rem' }}>
      <Grid container justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center">
        <Grid item xs={12} md={9}>
          <Typography>Some question-label related to my radiogroup</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={3}>
          <Controller
            rules={{ required: true }}
            control={control}
            name="myRadioGroupName"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormControl component="fieldset">
                <RadioGroup row {...field}>
                  <FormControlLabel
                    value="yes"
                    control={<Radio data-testid="myRadioGroupYes" />}
                    label="Yes"
                  />
                  <FormControlLabel
                    value="no"
                    control={<Radio data-testid="myRadioGroupNo" />}
                    label="No"
                  />
                </RadioGroup>
              </FormControl>
            )}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      {myRadioGroupValue === 'yes' && (
      <>
        <Typography>Fill the box below with any additional information</Typography>
        <TextField
          {...register('myRadioGroupName-additionalInfo')}
          placeholder="Enter relevant additional information"
          fullWidth
        />
      </>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

---

EDIT 2023-03: You can also set the defaultValue for a `Controller` component directly from its attributes like so:

```js
<Controller
  name="myRadioGroupName"
  rules={{ required: true }}
  defaultValue={null}
  render={({ field }) => (
    ...
  )}
/>
```

Comment: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/#defaultValues

Thank you this answer helped me get passed that same error with the radio button group I was trying to implement in a work project. I wasn't using useWatch like you, but the docs showed me another way to set the values for each value on my form when you call the hook.

Comment: lol SO has helped me many times and I'm happy to pass along the favor! After working with react-hook-form some more, I realized that you can pass the `defaultValue` directly in the `<Controller... />` component itself rather than having to specify it in the `useForm` hook. I added an edit to the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I tried to pass the default value right to the controller and was still getting the error in the console. Setting the default value in the hook was the only thing that cleared it for me, just fyi.